# Should seizure inducing content be removed, or otherwise handled in a certain way?

Tags: discussion

So I just saw this edit in the review queue:

https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/140434

The user wants to add a big warning and a bunch of scrolling distance to hide a flashing image from those to whom it might be harmful. I rejected the edit because it seems overly destructive to the post. But it begs the question: how do we handle this?

For now, I will just remove the image. I will post the reasoning as an answer, since it gives one possible answer to 'how to handle this'.

Comment: Is there a spolier filter we could add?

Comment: @schroeder It appears that exists nowadays: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1191/192262 But in this implementation, we'd still need a warning with enough emphasis that someone reads it as first thing before even so much as hovering over the spoiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As someone personally affected by this, I would highly encourage a clear warning label on potentially seizure-inducing content. Showing the content by default can be very, very unpleasant for many people, including me.

Comment: Thanks for providing a first-hand account! I don't (edit: didn't :) ) know anyone affected by this and have also heard people say that the impact of flashing images is exaggerated. Good to hear from someone who actually knows.

Comment: @Luc Depends on the case. For example, a strobe light is an absolute no-go for me, but most videogames are fine for me, even if they include a "seizure warning" or "photosensitivity warning". The content in said question, for instance, is rather on the "no-go" side for me.

Answer (score 4):

For accessibility, yes, we should not have seizure-inducing content laid bare in a post.

Either alternatives should be used or the content hosted with a click-thru mechanism with a warning.

Answer (score 1):

The user could leave a reference (the non-gif version) that contains the activating content.

Answer (score 0):

At least in this case, it appears the image can be removed, since there is no need for a potentially dangerous (to humans, not security-wise) image to be used as a demo. The author of the question could find a better demo if they think a demonstration of the issue is required.

It does feel destructive to the post, however, so I'm not sure if I should be the one looking for a better demo.